# Data format issue with passing data between JavaScript and C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, fullcalendar, momentjs

The structure is like this:

Test.aspx:

```html
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="PartTimeFrontendMockup.Test" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700&display=fallback"/>
  <!-- Font Awesome Icons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css"/>
  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link id="stileAdminLTE" runat="server" rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/adminlte.min.css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.7.2/main.min.css"  crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />


</head>
<body>
          <div class="card card-warning">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="card-title">Selezione date Part-time</h3>
              </div>
              <!-- /.card-header -->
              <!-- form start -->
              <form class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
            <!-- small card -->
            <div class="small-box bg-success">
              <div class="inner">
                <h3><span id="spanPTPerc">0</span><sup style="font-size: 20px">%</sup></h3>
                <p>Percentuale part-time</p>
              </div>
              <div class="icon">
                <i class="fas fa-calculator"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
                    </div>
                      <div class="card bg-blue col-sm-8 form-inline">
                    <label for="inputdalle" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Dalle</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputdalle" placeholder="Dalle" value="6:30"/>
                    </div>
                          <label for="inputalle" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Alle</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputalle" placeholder="Alle" value="12:30"/>
                    </div>
</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.card-body -->
                <div class="card-footer">
                </div>
                <!-- /.card-footer -->
              </form>
            </div>
<div id="PTCalendar"></div>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Momentjs -->
<script src="plugins/moment/moment.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
<script src="plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="dist/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-loading-overlay/2.1.7/loadingoverlay.min.js" integrity="sha512-hktawXAt9BdIaDoaO9DlLp6LYhbHMi5A36LcXQeHgVKUH6kJMOQsAtIw2kmQ9RERDpnSTlafajo6USh9JUXckw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.7.2/main.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.7.2/locales-all.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="js/PTMockup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Test.aspx.cs:

```cs
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
    using PartTimeBackend;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    namespace PartTimeFrontendMockup
    {
        public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!IsPostBack) {
                    if (Request["Action"] == "GetPTPercentage") {
    
                        string ss = "";
                        JObject j = new JObject();
                        JArray eventi=(JArray) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Request["eventi"]);
                        PTEvent pte = new PTEvent();
                        List<DateTime> LDT = new List<DateTime>();
                        DateTime dtdalle = new DateTime();
                        DateTime dtalle = new DateTime();
                        foreach (JObject evt in eventi) {
                            JProperty dalle = evt.Property("start");
                            JProperty alle = evt.Property("end");
    
                            dtdalle = Convert.ToDateTime(dalle.First.Value<String>());
                            dtalle = Convert.ToDateTime(alle.First.Value<String>());
                            pte.AddDateFromMisto(dtdalle, dtalle);
                        }
    
                        double asd = pte.PTpercentage;
                        string perc = String.Format("{0:0.0}", asd) ;
    
    
                        Response.Clear();
                        string ret = "OK";
                        
                        if (ret == "OK")
                        {
                            j.Add("Stato", "OK");
                            j.Add("perc", perc);
    
    
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            j.Add("Stato", "KO");
                            j.Add("Errore", ret);
                        }
                        Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(j));
                        Response.End();
        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Finally, classes file:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Linq;
    using EWSoftware.PDI;
    using System.Data.Common;
    using PartTimeBackend.models;
    using EWSoftware.PDI.Objects;
    using EWSoftware.PDI.Properties;
    using EWSoftware.PDI.Parser;
    using EWSoftware.PDI.Binding;
    using System.Web;
    
    namespace PartTimeBackend
    {
        public class PTEvent
        {
            public DateTime StartDateTimePT { get; set; }
            public DateTime EndDateTimePT { get; set; }
            public TimeSpan totalWorkingTime;
            public double PTpercentage;
            public string PTperc;
            public int totDates;
            public VCalendar vc;
    
            public List<DateDuration> DDL;
            public List<DateTime> datesChecker;
    
            public PTEvent()
            {
                this.vc = new VCalendar();
                DDL = new List<DateDuration>();
                totDates = 0;
                PTpercentage = 0;
                totalWorkingTime = new TimeSpan();
                datesChecker = new List<DateTime>();
                StartDateTimePT = DateTime.Today;
                EndDateTimePT = DateTime.Today;
            }
    
    
            public void AddDateFromMisto(DateTime dtFrom, DateTime dtTo)
            {
                DateDuration dd = new DateDuration();
                RRuleProperty rrp = new RRuleProperty();
                VEvent nve = new VEvent();
                dd.dalle = dtFrom;
                dd.alle = dtTo;
                nve.RecurDates.Add(dtFrom);
                this.DDL.Add(dd);
                GetPTPercentage();
    
            }
    
            private void CalculateTOTs()
            {
                var distinctItems = this.DDL.Distinct();
                this.totDates = this.DDL.Distinct().Count();
            }
    
    
            public string GetPTDates()
            {
                string allDates = "";
                foreach (var x in this.DDL)
                {
                    allDates += "date: " + x.dalle + "\t duration: " + x.Duration + "\r\n";
                }
                return allDates;
    
            }
    
            public void GetPTPercentage()
            {
    
                CalculateTOTs();
                var distinctItems = this.DDL.Distinct();
                TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan();
                foreach (var xx in distinctItems)
                {
                    ts += xx.Duration;
                }
                this.PTpercentage = ((ts.TotalHours) / 1872) * 100;
                this.totalWorkingTime = ts;
            }
        }
    
        public class DateDuration
        {
            public DateTime dalle;
            public DateTime alle;
    
            public TimeSpan Duration
            {
                get { return alle - dalle; }
            }
        }
    }
```

The web oage should work like this:
Whenever a user clicks on a date, the date should be marked as an event, the `<span id="spanPTPerc">0</span>` content should hold percentage of the Part-Time.

My problem can be summed into two major issues:

1. How can I debug the whole process? That would help trace the change in values in the variables and edit the code accordingly.
2. Is there a problem in the passing of the event data to C#? I think the whole issue relies in the conversion between datetime and the JavaScript's moment.js

**Update:** whenever I try to printout the JArray variable "eventi", i it is always "[]" which should indicate an empty array .. that might be the problem.

**Mockup.js**

```
function popErrore(testo) {
    Swal.fire({
        icon: 'error',
        title: 'Oops...',
        text: testo,
    })

}
/* initialize the calendar
 -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
//Date for the calendar events (dummy data)
var date = new Date()
var d = date.getDate(),
    m = date.getMonth(),
    y = date.getFullYear()

var Calendar = FullCalendar.Calendar;
var Draggable = FullCalendar.Draggable;

var containerEl = document.getElementById('external-events');
var checkbox = document.getElementById('drop-remove');
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('PTCalendar');

// initialize the external events
// -----------------------------------------------------------------

var j = [];
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
    locale: 'it',
    headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev,next',
        center: 'title',
        right: ''
    },
    eventOverlap:false,
    themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
    eventDidMount: function (info) {
        if (info.event.display != 'background') {
            $(info.el).popover({
                animation: true,
                delay: 300,
                html: true,
                content: info.event.extendedProps.description,
                trigger: 'hover'
            });
        }
    },
});
calendar.render();
/* AGGIUNTA EVENTI */

function addNew(info) {
    var strdalle = $("#inputdalle").val();
    var stralle = $("#inputalle").val();
    var dalle = new moment(info.dateStr +" "+ strdalle, "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm")
    var alle = new moment(info.dateStr + " " + stralle, "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm")

    var myEvent = {
     
        title: "Part Time dalle " +strdalle + " alle " +stralle,
        start: dalle,
        end: alle,
        description:'Part Time',
        display:'block',
        backgroundColor: 'green',
        allDay: false

    };
          
    calendar.addEvent(myEvent);
}

calendar.on('dateClick', function (info) { 
addNew(info);
$.post('Test.aspx',   // url
    {   
        Action: 'GetPTPercentage',
        eventi: JSON.stringify(calendar.getEvents()),
    }, // data to be submit
    function (data, status, jqXHR) {// success callback
        var jObj = JSON.parse(data);
        if (jObj.Stato == "OK") {
            $("#spanPTPerc").text(jObj.perc);

        } else {
            popErrore(jObj.Errore);
        }
    })

});
```

Comment: Are you developing this in Visual Studio? Then debugging should be as easy as pressing F5 (Debug) by default...

Comment: Yes, visualStudio 2017, but i have no idea on how to trace external variables. for example, if I need to trace the momentjs variables and view the conversion process between javascript and c# i opt to normally log the variables usingt the `console.log` function in javascript. Is there a way to trace that in visual studio? that would be very helpful in tyring to trace the root of the problem ..

Comment: You can use the browser's Network tool to see what is being sent back and forth between the browser and the server, and, as you say use the Console in the browser to log anything which happens in JS. Your browser also has a Javascript debugger built-in, similar to Visual Studio's C# debugger.

Comment: `Is there a problem in the passing of the event data to C#`... we can't see any of your Javascript code either, so it's very difficult to assess what is happening.

Comment: @ADyson, i just added the Mockup.js file contents that I created.

Comment: Ok. So did you do what I suggest and use the various debuggers and tools to see what is actually being sent to the server, and what response you get? Have you debugged what `Request["eventi"]` contains in the C#? etc. We can't really debug it just from the code. I wanted to see the JS just to check you hadn't made a really fundamental mistake, and I can't see an obvious one.